# how to add radio buttons in flows

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow, sfdc-styleguide

I am new to flows i just want to create radio button in screen element

Rating // WHERE RATING is my label AND 1 to 5 values are my custom values

1

2

3

4

5

help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use screen flow and drag the standard radio button option for this and configure it based on your requirement.[Click here for details about radio button.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_radio.htm&type=5)

[image: Please refer this for more deatils]

Comment: thank you Kalpana